# Contour plots limitations for stats models

Tags: data-visualization, experiment-design, uncertainty

My team prefers to present the models by using contour plots.

[image]

Although I understand that they are looking nice I don't like them because they don't present the model's uncertainty but only the mean.

Instead I prefer to use something like the below where the model error is presented.

Notice that normally our data is small, are coming from lab experiments studying many factors using design of experiments (DoE) and the processes have anything but small repeatability error. In DoE literature the contour plots are used extensively but mostly in specific Response Surface methods and not in every case.

Is there any resource discussing this issue? What are the limitations of the contour plots and when they should be used?

[image]

Comment: Maybe a 3D plot with the predicted surface and the upper and lower confidence surfaces? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/246038/binary-binomial-logistic-regression-with-multiple-independent-variables-calcu/246047#246047.

Comment: Reasonable idea but a static 3D is difficult plot to read, an interactive 3D could do it but cannot be included in a word document

Comment: If you would expand on your objective, that would help.  Is it about individual or mean predictions?  Who is your audience?  Your example has symmetry about the predictions so a separate contour plot with the confidence or prediction half-widths would supply information about the precision.